# Does a Finite Field with Four Elements Actually Exist?

Tags: field-theory

dear StackExchange community, so once again I'm confused with this problem concerning finite fields. The given field has four elements with the addition table as

$$\begin{array}{c|c|c|} 
+ & 0 & 1 & x & x + 1 \\ \hline
0 & 0 & 1 & x & x + 1 \\ \hline
1 & 1 & 0 & x + 1 & x \\ \hline
x & x & x + 1 & 0 & 1 \\ \hline
x + 1 & x + 1 & x & 1 & 0 \\ \hline
\end{array}$$

and multiplication table as

$$\begin{array}{c|c|c|} 
\times & 0 & 1 & x & x + 1 \\ \hline
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ \hline
1 & 0 & 1 & x & x + 1 \\ \hline
x & 0 & x & x + 1 & 1 \\ \hline
x + 1 & 0 & x + 1 & 1 & x \\ \hline
\end{array}$$

Now the question I'm supposed to answer is *"Does a finite field with four elements actually exist?"*. I know the answer to this question must be yes (via looking at multiple threads here) and I could argue the existence by proving every field axiom, but I don't think that is the wanted solution (proving distribution law would also take forever).

I'm just very confused about the question itself. My course is still very elementary and I don't understand the meaning of a field to exist. Maybe the question is poorly worded? I just don't know. Any help would be nice and thank you in advance.

Comment: Your multiplication table can't be right since $x + 1 \ne 0 \Longrightarrow (x + 1)^2 \ne 0$.  How about $(x + 1)^2 = x$?

Comment: I made a mistake. I corrected it. Thanks.

Comment: Checking for distributivity and associativity isn't *too* bad. You can quickly show that $a(b+c)=ab+ac$ is true when any of $a,b,c$ are zero, and that it's true when $a=1$. By commutativity of addition (which is easy to check at a glance on the table), if it's true for $a,b,c$ then it's true for $a,c,b$. So now you only have to check $2\cdot6=12$ possibilities - $2$ possibilities for $a$ other than $0$ and $1$, and $6$ possible choices for $b,c$.

Comment: Why did you accept an answer that does not address your question, nor shed any light on the mathematics behind finite fields? Are you actually interested in the mathematics?

Comment: @user21820 I thought it was helpful at least in that moment. Maybe I should have thought about it more carefully. I'm outside right now, but I'll try to look at the answers till tomorrow. I'm sorry if it wasn't the correct choice.

Comment: @user21820 I saw the huge comment chain under one of the answers and I just want to say that it is often hard for me to pick the best answer. Almost every answer I get is helpful and if possible I wouldn't want to pick a "best answer". But I know that I'm expected to do so. Either way, I'll look into it.

Comment: @matt: The answer you picked is an answer to a different question, namely that to prove that a field with four elements exists, you literally have to prove that there exists a collection with binary operations on it (and usually two constants) that satisfy the field axioms. However your question **instead** asks how to check the distribution law given the tables. Indeed only my answer and Ross' attempt to, though his will only help you for this specific example while mine works for any finite field in general.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're asked whether something exists, and you want to assert that it does, an effective way is to probably just construct it!

What I mean by this is that you have been asked whether a certain thing exists (a field with $4$ elements), and you want to assert that it does. What you can do is say yes, and prove that what you are asserting is a field with $4$ elements actually is one.

The meaning of "does a field exist?", is exactly what it says. They want you to prove it by giving them an example of one, or disprove it by providing a proof to the contrary.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. ... but what concrete example could fit into $x + x = 0$? Bernard mentioned $(X^2 + X + 1)$ so something in that form?

Comment: Ah. This is perhaps where you're having trouble. When we do algebra, we would say that you *have* constructed an example with your tables in your question. You don't actually need to know "what it is" in the sense that you're asking me. However, $\mathbb{Z}_2 \times \mathbb{Z}_2$ I think does what you're after. This has elements $(0,0), (0,1), (1,0), (1,1)$, and with the appropriately defined multiplication gives you what you want (I think).

Comment: I think I could solve it. Either way, I understood field theory more than before. Thank you very much.

Comment: @MattS - $\Bbb Z_2 \times \Bbb Z_2$ is used to denote the ring where both multiplication and addition are defined coordinate-wise. Since $(0,1)\cdot(1,0) = (0,0)$, this is not a field. Thus the 4-element field, whose multiplication is different, is commonly denoted by $F_4$.

Comment: -1: this answer fails to address the OP's concern. The OP expresses that he could check the axioms, but very reasonably notes that checking associativity and/or distributivity is a huge pain. This answer offers nothing in that light.

Comment: @MartinArgerami I have to disagree. The OP does say that, but it's not the point of the question. The point of the question is clearly: "I'm just very confused about the question itself. My course is still very elementary and I don't understand the meaning of a field to exist. Maybe the question is poorly worded? I just don't know. Any help would be nice and thank you in advance.". The point of the question is clearly *not* the part (actually specifically in brackets): "(proving distribution law would also take forever).". I DO address OPs question, and leave out the bit OP put in brackets.

Comment: I agree with you, @MartinArgerami.  This is generic advice, not an answer, that could have been more succinct, and best posted as a comment.

Comment: I respectfully disagree with both of you. To me, the question clearly indicates a need for "generic advice", as it is thoroughly non-specific. The only *question* OP actually asked was "maybe the question is poorly worded?". I explained what the meaning of "does a field exist?" was - something OP expressed confusion over, and explain what OP had been asked to do. Giving a ridiculously specific example or technical answer in this case would to my mind not solve any of the problems that OP actually has. Having said that, I appreciate your comments, and will take them on board in future.

Comment: You may disagree with two commenters, @MattS, who find little value in your answer.  Indeed, it looks like, given your absurd comment below the first comment, that you *know little on the topic*.  It's not difference than if I were to say:  "Reread your question;  read the definition you're learned as to how a field is defined.  Make up something so it satisfies the definitions of a field."  Substitute (where "field" appears, the word "group" or "determinate ", or "equivalence relation",) and you've got an algorithm to write an *unhelpful* answer almost anywhere on this site.

Comment: Matt S  Making up some field is *still going to require you to demonstrate it satisfies the field axioms*.  Give credit to the commenters here who helped, after the askers suggestion failed miserably.  So you're back to square one, with a suggestion for a field (as demonstrated in your tables) and other answers, comments.  So it escapes me entirely that you accepted this answer.  Of course, you can accept any answer you want, or none at all.  But I'd think twice if I were you.

Comment: I don't particularly understand why your opinion on how much I know on the topic is relevant to my answer to the question. My answer was in fact *completely* different to what you suggest as an analogy, which is probably why *my answer got accepted*. Your opinion on my answer is as valid as anyone else's, but you seem somehow irate that I disagree with you about it being unhelpful (as did anyone else who up-voted my answer, along with OP). I did give you credit, in my remark above, which you apparently failed to properly read. *Calm down*.

Comment: The intrusion of pop psychology ("irate", "calm down") as a substitute for rational dscussion is rarely a good sign for the validity of the arguments surrounding it.

Comment: Ironically, if I might add, I am all in favor of notifications to the OP that their question betrays the fact that they did not even check the relevant basic definitions before posting, when this is so, but not that such notifications be posted as answers (rather as comments on main, possibly together with a vote to close).

Answer (score 7):

I think you are supposed to verify the axioms.  The ones for addition and multiplication are easy-you can just point to the groups that they represent.  As you say, distributivity is the hard one.  Nominally, given that addition is comutative you have $24$ cases to check, four multiplies times six sums.  Half of them are trivial because they are multiplying by $0$ or $1$.  That only leaves $12$, which isn't so many.  I would do them and declare victory.

Answer (score 5):

A field with $4$ elements is easily built: consider the quotient field $\;\mathbf Z/2\mathbf Z[X]/(X^2+X+1)$. It is a field because the polynomial $X^2+X+1$ is irreducible over $\mathbf Z/2\mathbf Z$, as it is a quadratic polynomial with no root inAlso, as a $\mathbf Z/2\mathbf Z$-vector space, it has dimension $2$, hence its cardinality is $4$.

The tables you provide reflect the laws on this quotient. For instance
$x(x+1)=x^2+x\equiv -1$ since $x^2+x+1\equiv0$, and $-1\equiv1$ in 
 $\mathbf Z/2\mathbf Z$.

Comment: I suspect you are using machinery not available to OP.  I would guess that the question comes up early in a course in field theory.

Comment: I suspect that the phrase "My course is still very elementary" (among others) unfortunately implies that this proof will be of little assistance. I find it difficult to believe that OP will understand practically anything that you've provided.

Comment: Maybe you're right. However the argument are *very* elementary: they suppose the notion of irreducible polynomial, dimension of a vector space and the high school $\mathbf Z/2\mathbf Z$.

Comment: I completely forgot about modular! Thanks, I think I get it now. I'll try for myself.

Comment: You had a really nice high school if they got anywhere near the concept of Z/2Z.

Comment: You had a really nice high school where they introduced the concept of finite fields

Comment: @WorldSEnder: I had not myself (I'm too old for that), but I was a high school teacher for a few years, and at the time, the curriculum included elementary notions about groups, rings, fields  and vector spaces from grade 10.

Answer (score 2):

Simply observe that addition and multiplication as defined in the table is equivalent to addition and multiplication of integer polynomials in $x$ modulo $2$ and modulo $x^2+x+1$, and then observe that they commute in a certain sense.
$
\def\zz{\mathbb{Z}}
$

Namely, for any $f,g \in \zz[x]$ define:

$f \oplus g = (f+g) \bmod 2 \bmod (x^2+x+1)$.

$f \odot g = (f·g) \bmod 2 \bmod (x^2+x+1)$.

Then prove that for any $f,g,m \in \zz[x]$ we have:

$f \bmod m \bmod m = f \bmod m$.

$(f+g) \bmod m = ( f \bmod m + g \bmod m ) \bmod m$.

$(f·g) \bmod m = ( ( f \bmod m ) · ( g \bmod m ) ) \bmod m$.

Together these can be easily used to show (for you to do!) that associativity and commutativity and distributivity of $\oplus,\odot$ on the set of polynomials $F = \{0,1,x,x+1\}$ is equivalent to associativity and commutativity and distributivity of $+,·$ on integer polynomials, which is very easy to understand intuitively and prove.

Comment: Note that $F$ is simply the result of taking the whole set of integer polynomials in $x$ modulo $2$ and modulo $x^2+x+1$. This clearly shows that the ring structure is preserved under modulo. So the only thing we will need to check if we want the resulting structure to be a field is whether every element has a multiplicative inverse, since we already started with a commutative ring. And in fact this is the crucial issue.